# Actualizar total stock de productos

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

estoy intentando crear un stock a partir de los nuevos productos que se crean con las Compras del sistema.

Todas las `Compras` tienen un `ItemCompra`, con cierto **product_id y product.cantidad**, estos están anidados mediante un `accepts_nested_attributes_for` y la relación `has_many` al modelo `Compras`.

Suponiendo que en mi modelo `Compra` he creado un `ItemCompra` con un `Product_id` especifico, *por ejemplo: ItemCompra = **Zapatos Azules(:id => 14, :product_id => 5, :cantidad => 100)**. ¿Cómo actualizo la cantidad para el Producto de Zapatos Azules creado anteriormente en el `ItemCompra`? Esto sería en la tabla `Products` del sistema, Zapatos Azules, `:cantidad_disponible`

**Product.find(5).update(:cantidad_disponible)** (Zapatos Azules en el sistema, valor por defecto = 0)

Me gustaría realizarlo con un `before_save`, ya que cada vez que agrego un nuevo producto a X compra, el total para cada producto también debe actualizarse.

Modelo Compra

```
    class Compra < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :product
     has_many :item_compras, :dependent => :destroy
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_compras, 
     reject_if: RejectDeeplyNested.blank?,
     :allow_destroy => true

     before_save :charge_stock

     private

     def charge_stock
        #Aquí debería cargar el stock para cada product_id
     end
end
```

ItemCompra model

```
class ItemCompra < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :compra
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :calibre

    private
end
```

Product Model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :compras, :dependent => :restrict_with_error 
    has_many :compra_almacens, :dependent => :restrict_with_error
    has_many :item_compras

    def to_s
        "#{name} #{tipo}"
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí lo puedes hacer en un *callback* como `before_save`, pero hazlo directamente en el modelo `ItemCompra` el cual realmente indica la afectación en el *item*; y también te recomendaría hacerlo con `after_save` (en lugar de `before_save`), para no cambiar el inventario hasta que ya se haya guardado el valor en `ItemCompra`:

```
class ItemCompra < ActiveRecord::Base
    after_save :charge_stock

    belongs_to :compra
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :calibre

    private
    def charge_stock
        inventario = product.cantidad_disponible + cantidad
        self.product.update!(cantidad_disponible: inventario)
    end
end
```

Con `after_save` el método `charge_stock` se ejecutará hasta que `ItemCompra` haya sido guardado, lo que evitará que el inventario del producto aumente cuando el `ItemCompra` no se guarde.

Comment: Cuando creo un ItemCompra, este tiene un producto y una cantidad, al momento de guardarlo, se debería también actualizar la cantidad de productos en el sistema. por ej: ItemCompra = product_id: 1(Zapatos azules) cantidad: 100, al guardar, Product debería actualizarse igual, Product = cantidad 100 (Zapatos azules) si creo otra item compra, la cantidad de stock debe ir aumentando.

Comment: @MosiahRicardo Checa la respuesta actualizada, el inventario de `Product` ahora debe aumentar (en lugar de disminuir).